# Dynamic class redefinition at runtime

Tags: java, instrumentation, byte-buddy

I have been playing recently with java instrumentation API and a byte buddy. My goal is to change the behavior of an already loaded class. I was able to change the existing method but I`ve failed with adding a completely new one.

**First approach:**

```
public static void agentmain(String agentArgs, Instrumentation inst) throws ClassNotFoundException, UnmodifiableClassException {
    System.out.println(("[Agent] In agentmain/premain method"));

    Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("com.example.instrumentation.agent.AppService");

    inst.addTransformer(new AppServiceTransformer(), true);
    inst.retransformClasses(clazz);
}
```

```
public class AppServiceTransformer implements ClassFileTransformer {

    @Override
    public byte[] transform(ClassLoader loader, String className, Class<?> classBeingRedefined, ProtectionDomain protectionDomain, byte[] classfileBuffer) throws IllegalClassFormatException {
        byte[] byteCode = null;
        System.out.println("Transformation");
        try {
            byteCode = new ByteBuddy()
                .redefine(classBeingRedefined)
//                .defineMethod("getExperimental", String.class, Opcodes.ACC_PUBLIC)
//                .intercept(FixedValue.value("This is a message from the ByteBuddy hacker !!!"))
                .method(named("getAnswer"))
                .intercept(FixedValue.value("Service has been hacked :)"))
                .make()
                .getBytes();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            System.err.println(e);
            System.err.println("Failed to transform");
        }
        return byteCode;
    }
}
```

Above code works, when I attach this agent to an already running VM it alters the behavior of the specified method. However when I uncomment the code responsible for defining a new method what I get is a

`Exception in thread "main" com.sun.tools.attach.AgentInitializationException: Agent JAR loaded but agent failed to initialize`

I tried running above example as a premain agent loaded at application start-up. For this case altering the behaviour of a the method works but adding a new one throws

```
Failed to transform
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:513)
    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:525)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: class redefinition failed: attempted to add a method
```

**Second approach:**

```
    public static void agentmain(String agentArgs, Instrumentation inst) throws ClassNotFoundException, UnmodifiableClassException {
        System.out.println(("[Agent] In agentmain/premain method"));

        new AgentBuilder.Default()
            .type(named("com.jarek.example.instrumentation.agent.AppService"))
            .transform(new AgentBuilder.Transformer() {
                @Override
                public DynamicType.Builder<?> transform(DynamicType.Builder<?> builder, TypeDescription typeDescription, ClassLoader classLoader, JavaModule module) {
                    System.out.println("Entered transform");
                    return builder.method(named("getAnswer"))
                        .intercept(FixedValue.value("Service has been hacked :)"))
                        .defineMethod("getExperimental", String.class, Opcodes.ACC_PUBLIC)
                        .intercept(FixedValue.value("This is experimental feature"));
                }
            })
            .with(AgentBuilder.RedefinitionStrategy.REDEFINITION)
            .with(AgentBuilder.TypeStrategy.Default.REDEFINE)
            .installOn(inst);
    }
```

I can see in the console that the agent have entered the transform method, however the new method isn`t added to the class and the behaviour of the existing one is not altered.
Using this solution as a premain agent works perfectly in both cases.

**Third approach:**

```
    public static void premain(String agentArgs, Instrumentation inst) throws ClassNotFoundException, UnmodifiableClassException {
        System.out.println(("[Agent] In agentmain/premain method"));

        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("com.example.instrumentation.agent.AppService");

        ByteBuddyAgent.install();
        new ByteBuddy()
            .redefine(clazz)
//            .defineMethod("getExperimental", String.class, Opcodes.ACC_PUBLIC)
//            .intercept(FixedValue.value("This is a message from the ByteBuddy hacker !!!"))
            .method(named("getAnswer"))
            .intercept(FixedValue.value("Service has been hacked :)"))
            .make()
            .load(clazz.getClassLoader(), ClassReloadingStrategy.fromInstalledAgent());
}
```

This case works only for the premain agent for altering an existing method. The attempt to add a new method throws

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: class redefinition failed: attempted to add a method
```

When attaching this as a agent to already running application nothing happens.

1. *Does anybody knows if this is possible to achieve what I`ve been trying too ?*
2. *Which of those approaches is correct and why do they behave differently ?*
3. *How this is it possible that We can change the behaviour of a class which is already loaded to the VM?
   Has this mechanism some specific name? I've tried to look for some information on the internet but couldn't find anything.*
4. *Perhaps some other library i.e. JavaAssist or ASM would be better suited for this case?*

Comment: Can you please help me with the use-case you are trying to solve here?

Comment: It is just for learning purposes. I have some simple spring boot service that is already running. So the goal is to attach an agent to it and change some of its behavior. As I mentioned, I managed to alter some existing method of the service but failed when tried to add the new one.

Comment: From app design perspective,I recommend that for such kind of use cases you should keep that as application configuraton. This configuration should be kept in a DB and based on request you can get the correct config loaded into application and give response accordingly. If you give me a specific use-case then I can narrate better.

Comment: Let's consider the following situation. The app is running, I`m not allowed to change its source code but I want to develop some kind of framework/library which would help me do some profiling and gather metrics from that app. This agent is supposed to help me with that

Answer (score 2):

With an `AgentBuilder`, you should register a `Listener` to see if errors happen during retransformation. You probably should set `.disableClassFormatChanges()` as the average JVM does not support adding methods or fields to a class that already is defined.

Adding a field or method is impossible as it is today, only [the code evolution VM supports it as of today](https://github.com/dcevm/dcevm) and it is doubtful if this feature ever makes it to OpenJDK.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This answers my question, I`ll have to either try it with code evolution VM or do the redefinition at application start.

Comment: I am not sure but it seems in JDK 21 these limitation has been lifted. The part of the documentation in retransformClasses has this line in older JDKs "The retransformation must not add, remove or rename fields or methods, change the signatures of methods, or change inheritance" but this part has been removed in JDK 21 documentation.

Answer (score -1):

Since your requirement is to build a framework using which you can collect application metrics. Firstly, there are tools like [VisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io/) which helps you get metrics from a running java application and see the insights. This will be completely external to your application and won't require any code changes.

If you want a greater control over the metrics, you may onboard [Spring Boot Admin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-cloudfoundry/docs/1.2.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/configuration-monitoring-management.html) and this will do it realtime for you without any code changes. There are plethora of features present in Spring Boot Admin.